# buffer-substring fails in linux in a non-X terminal when I am in anything other than text mode

Tags: buffers

NOTE: I was careless in evaluating this problem, and the data I posted here is not correct and does not reflect the actual issue that I am facing.

Since there are already answers to this question, I cannot delete it.

Please see the following question for the updated and corrected version of my query:

[query-replace{-regexp} fails in linux in a non-X terminal when I am in anything other than text mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55757/query-replace-regexp-fails-in-linux-in-a-non-x-terminal-when-i-am-in-anything)

Please ignore the rest of this. Thank you.

I am running emacs 26.1 under linux. It has been working fine for over a year. Recently, I upgraded a lot of packages on my machine, but I did not upgrade nor alter emacs in any way. Now, `buffer-substring` is failing when I run it in a non-X terminal with the `-nw` emacs command-line flag when not in `text-mode`. This failure never used to occur before my system upgrades. And it turns out that `buffer-substring` still works fine in all cases when I start emacs in an X window.

For example, suppose I have the following data in a file called `test.txt` ...

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

If I run `emacs -nw test.txt`, then `(buffer-substring 0 1)` works. However, if I run `(elisp-mode)` and then do a `(buffer-substring 0 1)`, I get this error: `args-out-of-range #<buffer test.txt> 0 1`

This occurs no matter what arguments I pass to `buffer-substring`.  However, if I leave off `-nw` and do all the same things in an X-Window instance of emacs, `buffer-substring` always works.

In other words, with `emacs test.txt` (*i.e.*, no `-nw` flag), I never get this problem with `buffer-substring`, no matter what mode I am running in.

This is not only specific to `elisp-mode`. The error with `buffer-substring` in a non-X terminal buffer also occurs for `sh-mode` and some other modes.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error and what I have to do to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

I set `debug-on-error` and re-ran `(buffer substring 0 1)` in one of the cases that fails. Here is what I got:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range #<buffer test.txt> 0 1)
  buffer-substring(0 1)
  eval((buffer-substring 0 1) nil)
  eval-expression((buffer-substring 0 1) nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (buffer-substring 0 1) nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

FURTHER UPDATE:

This error does not occur when I am running from my system console (with no X services running at all). The errors I saw did occur in `xterm` and `urxvt` windows under my X desktop manager, even when I have explicitly unset `DISPLAY`.

It seems like there is something about running within an X desktop manager which is confusing emacs with regard to buffer attributes when running with `-nw`, even with `DISPLAY` unset.

Comment: The *first* thing to do in situations like this is to enable `debug-on-error` and then cause the error to happen again. That will give you a backtrace that you should add to your question. You can enable `debug-on-error` with `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET` (assuming that it was disabled before - if not, just toggle it again. The echo area should say `Debug on Error enabled globally`.)

Comment: See UPDATE above. The stack trace gives no useful information

Comment: `~ $ emacs -Q --batch --eval '(buffer-substring 0 1)' ` => `Args out of range: #<buffer *scratch*>, 0, 1`

Comment: This is because `*scratch*` is an empty buffer in your example. However, when running in a non-empty buffer as I have outlined above, `(buffer-substring 0 1)` works, except in the error cases I mentioned.

Comment: What is `elisp-mode` ?

Answer (score 1):

Buffer positions are 1-based, not 0-based.

You asked for buffer position 0:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range #<buffer test.txt> 0 1)
  buffer-substring(0 1)
```

You say:

> If I run `emacs -nw test.txt`, then `(buffer-substring 0 1)` works.

Are you sure? I don't see that.

Comment: And people usually should use `(point-min)` instead 1.

Comment: You are correct. I now realize that was misrepresenting my problem. It's actually related to `query-replace` and `query-replace-regexp`. They each generate the buffer-substring`out-of-range` error under the cases I described. I will discard this incorrectly described problem and repost something more accurate (tomorrow, since it's past my bedtime now). Thanks to all.

Comment: @xuchunyang: It depends what the intention is - whether to take narrowing into account.

Comment: @Drew That was my thought too, that's why I use the word "usually", but I just notice  `(buffer-substring 1 10)` will signal an error if [1, 10] is not showing because of narrowing. Thus, you still need `widen` first, then, it seems `point-min` is always preferred.

Comment: @xuchunyang: The point is that if you want it to work also with a narrowed buffer then the positions you give it need to either (a) be within the current buffer restriction or (b) be determined by sexp evaluation (e.g., position relative to `point-min`, `point-max`, not relative to `0` and `buffer-size`).