# query-replace{-regexp} fails in linux in a non-X terminal when I am in anything other than text mode

Tags: buffers, query-replace, query-replace-regexp

I am running emacs 26.1 under linux. It has been working fine for over a year. Recently, I upgraded a lot of packages on my machine, but I did not upgrade nor alter emacs in any way. Now, `query-replace` and `query-replace-regexp` are failing when I run either of them in a non-X terminal with the `-nw` emacs command-line flag when not in `text-mode`. This failure never used to occur before my system upgrades. And it turns out that `query-replace{-regexp}` still work fine in all cases when I start emacs in an X window.

For example, suppose I have the following data in a file called `test.txt` ...

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

If I run `emacs -nw test.txt`, then position to the top of the file and run `(query-replace "AAAA" "XXXX")`, it works. However, if I run `(emacs-lisp-mode)` and then run `(query-replace "AAAA" "XXXX")` in the same way, I get this result (with `debug-on-error` set) ...

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range #<buffer test.txt> 0 1)
  buffer-substring-no-properties(0 1)
  perform-replace("AAAA" "XXXX" t nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
  query-replace("AAAA" "XXXX")
  eval((query-replace "AAAA" "XXXX") nil)
  eval-expression((query-replace "AAAA" "XXXX") nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (query-replace "AAAA" "XXXX") nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

However, if I leave off `-nw` and do all the same things in an X-Window instance of emacs, `(query-replace ...)` always works.

In other words, with `emacs test.txt` (*i.e.*, no `-nw` flag), I never get this problem with `query-replace`, no matter what mode I am running in.

This is not only specific to `emacs-lisp-mode`. The error with `query-replace` in a non-X terminal buffer also occurs for `sh-mode` and some other modes.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error and what I have to do to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

This error does not occur when I am running from my system console (*i.e.*, no X services running at all). The errors I saw did occur in `xterm` and `urxvt` windows under my X desktop manager, even when I have explicitly unset `DISPLAY`.

It seems like there is something about running within an X desktop manager which is confusing emacs with regard to buffer attributes when running with `-nw`, even with `DISPLAY` unset.

And again, this problem only started happening a short time ago after updating a number of software components, but with *no* changes to emacs, at all. I have rebooted a few times since then, to no avail.

FURTHER UPDATE:

This error does not occur when I run `(replace-string "AAAA" "XXXX")`.

Comment: I cannot replicate this in GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw scroll bars) of 2018-10-23

Comment: OOPS: I meant  that I can edit an *.el file where `major-mode` gets set to `emacs-lisp-mode`, and I then get this error behavior.
Also, I know this is nearly impossible to reproduce. I am running emacs-26.1 on two other machines, and this behavior doesn't occur.

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to be related to the `font-lock` command when running it in an `emacs -nw` session. If I comment out all `(font-lock ...)` code in all my startup files, then this error behavior goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue by building and starting to use `emacs-28.0.50`:
https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs

I had to update some ancient, deprecated constructs in some of my old startup files so that this version of emacs would run. But in any case, this problem with `query-replace{-regexp}` doesn't exist in 28.0.50.

I still don't understand how making system changes outside of emacs could have caused this problem to suddenly appear in my stable-for-over-a-year `emacs-26.1`, but ...

```
Mine not to make reply,
Mine not to reason why,
Mine but to do and die.
```

(Apologies to Alfred, Lord Tennyson)

PS: `emacs-27.0.60` also works fine for me, without this problem.

Comment: I do recommend testing with the `emacs-27` branch if you've not already done so -- if that also works, then it would be a good idea to be using that instead of `master`, as there should be a stable 27.1 release sometime within the next few months, at which point you could switch to that.  28.0.50 is at a very early stage of development, and might be less stable.

Comment: Thank you. I have cloned and built the `emacs-27` branch, and it also fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW (this isn't an answer; just more context)

In 26.3, the only call to `buffer-substring-no-properties` in `perform-replace` is:

```el
(setq search-string-replaced (buffer-substring-no-properties
                              (match-beginning 0)
                              (match-end 0))
      ...)
```

So to get `buffer-substring-no-properties(0 1)` in the backtrace, we need `(match-beginning 0)` to return zero.

We're well into C code at that point, and establishing whether anything can ever set `search_regs.start[0]` to zero.

`perform-replace` does plenty with the match data, so I've not tried to figure out how that might happen.

Comment: Thank you for all this!  It turns out that if I do *NOT* set `font-lock-keyword-face`, the problem goes away. All other font-lock face settings work fine. So perhaps the matching code can sometimes get confused when it sees whatever emacs puts into a non-X-based buffer (i.e., when running with `-nw`) for keywords when I'm running in my particular X environment. I'll keep digging through the C and elisp code to try to figure out more about this.

Comment: If you're able, I would recommend trying/compiling an Emacs 27 build and seeing whether the problem still manifests.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't quickly find 27, but I did find version 28 on github. However, some things in the language have changed, and a few of my startup files don't work under 28. I'll work through this later, when I have some time. One of the non-emacs packages I upgraded was qt5, and it has lots of dependencies with fonts, X resources, etc., which had to be rebuilt as part of the upgrade. I'm thinking that this is somehow related to my problem. Also, I have installed 26.3 now, and my problem continues. I'll keep digging in my spare time.

Comment: If you're compiling it from git sources, then the `emacs-27` branch is for Emacs 27.

Comment: It turns out that version 28 fixes my problem. See my answer, below. Thank you again for all your help!